# Scala Flatmap on Array inside the part of the value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I have RDD like (a,b,Array(p1,p2,p3),c), I want to apply flatmap on Array inside the value to get the below output like.
(a,b,p1,c)
(a,b,p2,c)
(a,b,p3,c)

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: From java back ground, i'm very new to scala looking for some code snippet to apply flatmap on  array which in the part of value..

Answer (score 6):

Code:

```
val arr = Array(("a1", "b1", Array("1", "2", "3")),("a1", "b1", Array("1", "2", "3")))
val rdd: RDD[(String, String, Array[String])] = sc.parallelize(arr)
val result = rdd.flatMap {
  case (first, second, third) => {
    third.map(x => (first, second, x))
}}

println("Results: " + result.collect.mkString("|"))
```

Results:

```
Results: (a1,b1,1)|(a1,b1,2)|(a1,b1,3)|(a1,b1,1)|(a1,b1,2)|(a1,b1,3)
```